# Getting (AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.) error when loading word embeddings using a class

Tags: python, nlp

I have a python class Featurizer that checks for the existence of (Google news-vector embedding file) and loads if it exists or else throws an error message. The issue is am getting an error concerning atributeerror when i try to load it, i have failed to know what to change.

Trying to load the file embeddings

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim import models

word2vec_path = 'D:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
```

This is the class that is to check for the existence of the embeddings file

```
class Featurizer:

    def __init__(self, embedding_file):

        if not os.path.exists(embedding_file):
            raise IOError("Embeddings file does not exist: %s" %embedding_file)

        punctuation = string.punctuation
        punctuation = punctuation + "’" + "“" + "?" + "‘"
        self.punctuation = punctuation
        print('INFO: Loading word vectors...')
        self.word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
            embedding_file,
            binary=True)

        print('INFO: Done! Using %s word vectors from pre-trained word2vec.' \
            %len(self.word2vec.vocab))
```

When using the class Featurizer to load the embeddings

```
featurizer = Featurizer(word2vec_path)
```

It returns an error concerning the class

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\training_model.ipynb Cell 13' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 featurizer = Featurizer(word2vec_path)

d:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\training_model.ipynb Cell 4' in Featurizer.__init__(self, embedding_file)
     11 print('INFO: Loading word vectors...')
     12 self.word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
     13     'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',
     14     binary=True)
     16 print('INFO: Done! Using %s word vectors from pre-trained word2vec.' \
---> 17     %len(self.word2vec.vocab))

File d:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py:735, in KeyedVectors.vocab(self)
    733 @property
    734 def vocab(self):
--> 735     raise AttributeError(
    736         "The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.\n"
    737         "Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods "
    738         ".get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.\n"
    739         "See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4"
    740     )

AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.
Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.
```

What could be the issue and how can i correct it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `class init`, the `embedding_file` value is a string, but you're giving it another data type (keyed vector) while initializing your class, so unstead of this :

```
featurizer = Featurizer(w2v_model)
```

you should use smth like this:

```
featurizer = Featurizer(word2vec_path)
```

Comment: No initially, the embedding file wasn't speciied to str. I only added that ( embedding_file=str ) after it was returning the same error TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not KeyedVector..  Otherwise the new solution you just suggested i should use [featurizer = Featurizer(word2vec_path)] is giving off a new error (AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.)

Comment: i have made the changes like you suggested but i get a new error, look at the question edits i have made